# FB Javascript SDK: What's the point of the signed_request?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I remember all the stuff from the signed request for canvas apps: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Now I'm using the JS SDK (FB.login() method), which already gives you the auth token et al. as well as a signed request. Instead of the info that a canvas app's signed request gets, I get just:

`{"algorithm"=>"HMAC-SHA256", "code"=>"2.AQAdX5Zl5gY-Z_D7.3600.1322193600.1-XXXXX|HmarTBK09MSiB0o76cLgaTUd4y4", "issued_at"=>1322188281, "user_id"=>"XXXXXX"}`

So what confuses me is: what's the point of the JS SDK's `signed_request`? I already have all the info I need from just the login reply.

Answer (score 0):

when your app user comes to your `https://apps.facebook.com/myapp` he comes with  `signed_request`.

Then you serve your user to your `landing page`. In that `landing page` fb jsdk loads and writes to `cookies` to `browser`.

Then when user comes to your server he comes with these `cookies`. So writing `cookies` are not your job but fb jsdk's job.

Then your server reads those `cookies` and process further actions.

**Additional info**

While surfing at github, I found

> This client library is designed to support the Facebook Graph API and
>   the official Facebook JavaScript SDK, which is the canonical way to
>   implement Facebook authentication.

and

> If you are using the module within a web application with the
>   JavaScript SDK, you can also use the module to use Facebook for login,
>   parsing the cookie set by the JavaScript SDK for logged in users

Taken from [here](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/).

Answer (score 0):

There can be extra information provided in `signed_request` that isn't provided in the login response.

For example, if you need to check if a user is a fan of the page housing the app, this information is provided in `signed_request`. This can be injected into the page at load time by the server if the user is authenticated at that point, however if you are using an ajax authentication and `signed_request` were not provided in the login response, you wouldn't be able to check the fan status.